# CLIPS: How to test if a variable's type is a certain class?

Tags: clips, expert-system

I know there are several predicate functions that allow to test if a variable is of a certain type.
For example,

```
(test (integerp ?my_var))
```

returns `TRUE` if my_var is of type integer.

Say I have a class `A`. How do I test if a variable is of type `A`? That is, I want to test if `?my_var` is an instance of A.

I am looking for something like this:

```
(test (instance_of_A_p ?my_var))
```

or

```
(test (is-a (?my_var A))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the type function:

```
CLIPS> (bind ?a 3)
3
CLIPS> (type a)
SYMBOL
CLIPS> (defclass A (is-a USER))
CLIPS> (bind ?a (make-instance a1 of A))
[a1]
CLIPS> (type ?a)
A
CLIPS> (eq (type ?a) A)
TRUE
CLIPS>
```

So in the LHS of the rule:

```
(test (eq (type ?a) A))
```